# Iterate through web elements with Selenium and Robot Framework

Tags: loops, selenium, robotframework

On the web page there are many elements with the same span class name.
And I'm able to get the value of the first element with keyword 
"Get Text   class: ...".

But I just can not figure it out how to iterate and get the values of all those same span class names. Any ideas?

I know how to iterate e.g. a text file with Python, but I'm not yet familiar enough with Selenium and RFW.

Comment: Show a sample of the code you tried with; if you don't have such and don't know where to start from, the "For loops" section in the user guide is a good start

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get all web elements with same class using the `Get WebElements` keyword, and then you can iterate them with a `for` loop. Note that I am using the [RF 3.1 new `for` syntax](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-3.1.rst#for-loop-enhancements). You can access the text attribute using the [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax).

```python
${elements}=    Get WebElements    //span[@class='myclass']
FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
    Log    ${element.text}
END
```

Other option is to use the `Get Text` keyword inside the loop, you can pass the web element variable as a locator.

```python
${elements}=    Get WebElements    //span[@class='myclass']
FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
    ${text}=    Get Text    ${element}
    Log    ${text}
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution which you can try to itrate over all the element. **But if you want to take 1st element only then you** can create xpath and then add `(your xpath)[1]` to fetch 1st element. Similarly there is `:nth-childOf()`. Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_nth-child.asp)

```python
xpath=<<your identifier>>
${all_ele_count}=    Get Matching Xpath Count    xpath=<<your identifier>>
Log    ${all_ele_count}
: FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    1    ${all_ele_count}
\    Log    ${INDEX}
\    ${currUrl}    get location
\    click element    xpath=(<<your identifier>>)>1])[1]
\    do processing here
\    go to    ${currUrl}
```

Comment: This would mean doing a separate call to the browser for each element. Though it would technically work, I'd consider it a very slow approach. Using the `Get Webelements` approach fetches all of the elements in memory and thus only 1 interaction with the browser is needed.

Answer (score -2):

You can also get all the elements with the span class in an arraylist and iterate over them.
eg:

```
ArrayList<WebElement> list = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
list.add(driver.findElements(By.class("")));
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
{
//select the element which is needed
}
```

I hope this works

Comment: The OP seems to be interested in solving the problem using Robot FW and not java.